# Window.location nao funciona

Tags: javascript

Este Script tem por objectivo abrir uma url mediante selecção de valor em comobox
armazena os valor nas vars redir,redir2 e redir 3

```
function redirect(){
var obj = document.getElementById("cat");  // 
var obj2= document.getElementById("sub1");
var obj3= document.getElementById("sub2");
var redir2=obj2.options[obj2.selectedIndex].text.substring(0,4); 
var redir =obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text.substring(0,4); //
var redir3 =obj3.options[obj3.selectedIndex].text.replace(/ /g,"_");    

var url= redir+"/"+redir2+"/"+redir3+".php";
url=url.toLowerCase();

alert(url);

window.location.href = "np/categories/"+url;}
```

Consigo ver que o browser está  a assumir a linha de codigo, mas não abre a pagina de teste criada para o efeito

na console do mozilla vejo esta mensagem:

GET http://localhost/np/categories/auto/serv/test.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0 ms]

Todo o path está correto, no entanto a pagina não carrega, e simplesmente faz reload á pagina atual, onde faço a selecção.

O que é que está errado ?

Comment: E qual seria a URL atual?

Comment: http://localhost/np/combox/combox.php

Comment: Tente `window.location.href = "/np/categories/"+url;`

Comment: Obtenho este .log na consola

          GET http://localhost/np/categories/auto/serv/teste.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 16 ms]

Ele assume o codigo, mas nao carrega a pagina

Comment: Um método que funciona bem é usar `window.open('tua_url', '_self');`

Comment: mantem o mesmo problema. . assume e lê o codigo, mas nao carrega a pagina. Até agora só consegui carregar se for para abrir num outro separador....

Comment: esse metodo resulta, mas tive que o escrever da seguinte forma:

alert(window.open("/np/categories/"+url , '_self'));


Sem o alert nao funciona. Não percebo.

alguma sugestão ??